# Infinite continued fractions inequality

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, show that the inequality $e < \frac{a}{b} < \frac{87}{32}$ implies that $b \geq 39$.

This is exercise 15.3.7 b) from the book Elementary Number Theory by David M. Burton.

To our help we have the theorem (among many), $|x - a/b| < \frac{1}{b^2}$, if $a/b$ is the n:th convergent of the irrational number $x$.

Comment: After some thinking I get that $ e - 87/32 < a/b - 87/32 < 0$. Multiplying by (-1) yields that $a/b - 87/32 < |e-87/32|$. Now using the theorem gives that $a/b - 87/32 < |e-87/32| < 1/32^2$. So $a/b < 87/32 + 1/32^2$.

Comment: Your conclusion is slightly weaker than the given inequality, that does not really give much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial computation shows that the 6th and 7th convergents of $e$ are $C_6=\frac{{87}}{{32}}$ and $C_7=\frac{{106}}{{39}}$.  The result then follows due to the convergents being the best rational approximations to an irrational number (in this case $e$) in the sense that every other rational number with the same or smaller denominator differs from the irrational number by a greater amount.  In other words, $C_6$ shows that $b$ is greater than 32 and if $b$ were strictly between 32 and 39, then there would have been an intermediate convergent between $C_6$ and $C_7$ [*ERROR: this was my mistake; please see  Daniel Fischer's solution*].

This demonstration suffices to answer the posed question.  Note, however, that we can actually pass to the 8th convergent ($C_8 = \frac{{193}}{{71}}$) to obtain the stronger restriction $b\ge71$ by exploiting the fact that $e$'s even numbered convergents $C_{2n}$ are all greater than $e$ (the problem stipulates that we want a rational approximation greater than $e$) while $e$'s odd numbered convergents $C_{2n+1}$ are all less than $e$.  Note that I'm starting the convergent indexing at $C_1$ rather than $C_0$.

Comment: We have $\frac{106}{39} < e < \frac{87}{32}$. Since $87\cdot 39 - 106\cdot 32 = 1$, the two are successive fractions in the (extended) Farey series $\mathscr{F}_{39}$. Hence the unique fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ with the smallest denominator between $\frac{106}{39}$ and $\frac{87}{32}$ is the mediant of the two, $\frac{106 + 87}{39 + 32}$. This (with the appropriate $\mathscr{F}_n$ in place of $\mathscr{F}_{39}$) is the case for any two successive convergents of any real number. Since here the pertinent partial quotient of the continued fraction of $e$ is $1$, the mediant is the next convergent …

Comment: … and thus a best approximation. But even if it weren't the next convergent, whenever we have $\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} < x < \frac{p_n}{q_n}$ with successive convergents of the irrational number $x$, the mediant $\frac{p_{n+1} + p_n}{q_{n+1} + q_n}$ is the rational number with the smallest denominator satisfying $x < r < \frac{p_n}{q_n}$.